# Prove that $\left|\frac{x^p-1}{p}\right|\leq x+|\ln(x)|$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ and for all $p\in(0,1)$

Tags: analysis, absolute-value

So far I have shown that $$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{p\to 0^+}\frac{x^p-1}{p}=\lim\limits_{p\to 0^+}\frac{e^{p\ln(x)}-1}{p}=\ln(x)\lim\limits_{p\to 0^+}\frac{e^{p\ln(x)}-1}{p\ln(x)} =$$
(L'Hopital)
$$=\ln(x) \lim\limits_{p\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(x)e^{p\ln(x)}}{\ln(x)}=\ln(x).$$

But I don't know if it helps.

A hint would be more appreciated then the whole answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \geq 1$, then $LHS = \dfrac{-1+x^p}{p}, RHS = x + \ln x$. Thus we prove:
$x^p-1 \leq px +p\ln x\iff f(x)=-1+x^p-px -p\ln x \leq 0$. We have: $f'(x) = px^{p-1}-p-\dfrac{p}{x}=\dfrac{p}{x}\cdot (x^p-x-1)<0\to f(x) \leq f(1)=-p<0$. I leave the other part for you as a practice.

Comment: What is LHS and RHS?

Comment: $LHS , RHS $ are the left hand side and right hand side of the inequality, respectively.

Comment: Why is LHS=$\frac{1-x^p}{p}$? I mean, if $x\geq 1$, isn't $x^p\geq 1$?

Comment: Since $0 < p < 1, x^p \leq 1$. Example: $p = \dfrac{3}{7} \to x^3 \leq x^7 \to x^{\frac{3}{7}} \leq 1$.

Comment: But $\frac{x^3}{x^7}=x^{3-7}$ and not $x^{\frac{3}{7}}$

Comment: Thanks, let me fix it . I think it shouldn't be a major issue here.